# Facebook Graph API: How can I prolong data access for a 90-day access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

We get the access token by performing Facebook Oauth flow in our application. API issues a token that lasts 90 days, after that is stays valid, however, the data access expires.
When making a call for an account's posts, we just get an empty response due to the rules described here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/auth-vs-data/
How can I prolong the token? Apart from having users manually re-authorize.

Comment: There is no way except having the users manually re-authorize.